# ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object: (using laravel)

Tags: php, database, laravel, exception, laravel-5

ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object: PHP beginner

Trying to retreive data from database.

show.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

@section('title','| Station details')

@section('content')

    <h1>{{ $station->station_name }}</h1>

    <p class="lead">{{ $station->station_name }}</p>

@endsection
```

controller -

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Station;
use Session;

class StationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('stations.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // validate the data
        $this->validate($request, array(
                'station_name' => 'required|max:255',
                'date'=>'required'
            ));

        // store in the database
        $station = new Station;

        $station->station_name = $request->station_name;
        $station->date = $request->date;
        $station->PET = $request->PET;
        $station->max_temp = $request->max_temp;
        $station->min_temp = $request->min_temp;
        $station->min_rh = $request->min_rh;
        $station->solar_rad = $request->solar_rad;
        $station->rainfall = $request->rainfall;
        $station->wind4am = $request->wind4am;
        $station->wind4pm = $request->wind4pm;

        $station->save();

        Session::flash('success','Station data added');

        return redirect()->route('stations.show', $station->id);


        // redirect to another page
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $station = Station::find($id);

        return view('stations.show')->withStation('$station');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Database:-
[image: database]

Comment: Please post code on this site in the future

Comment: A line number normally goes with that error. That **would have been useful** and some indication in your code where that line exists as well

Comment: it's not showing any line number actually... and I'll post the code here itself thank you sir..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are returning the view in the following line:

```
return view('stations.show')->withStation('$station');
```

You need to either use double quotes or not use quotes at all. With the single quotes you are actually setting the value to the literal string `"$station"` instead of the object you created.

Answer (score 1):

You can try editing line 84 of your controller like this:

```
return $view->with(compact('station'));
```

Using compact is faster and cleaner in most cases since you already built the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Change method `public function create()` to:

```
public function create()
{
    $station = new Station;
    return view('stations.create')->with(compact('station'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please re-write `return view('stations.show')->withStation('$station');` like 
`return view('stations.show')->with(['station' => $station]);`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.