# laravel Trying to get property of non-object on null value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get data from the database but when one column has null value give me this error

> Trying to get property of non-object

the problem when assignTot is null give me the error if have value everything is ok.
How can I use a solution like `return view('stations.show')->withStation('$station');`
in my controll that return multiple as

> return view('admin.contracts.show',
>   compact('contracts','asiTo','tranTo','replies'));

```
public function show($id){
    $contracts=Contracts::find($id)
        ->where('contracts.id',$id)
        ->join('destination','contracts.condesid','destination.id')
        ->join('department','contracts.condepid','department.id')
        ->join('users','contracts.conassigneto','users.id')
        ->select('contracts.*','destination.name as desName','department.name  as depName','users.name as assignTot')
        ->first();
    return view('admin.contracts.show', compact('contracts'));
}
```

Blade:

```
<h2><span class="profile-details-name-nn">{{ $contracts->conhotelname }}</span></h2>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div class="btn-group project-list-ad">
        <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs">{{ $contracts->constatus }}</button>
    </div>
    <div class="project-details-dt">
        @if($contracts->assignTot == null)
            <span>-</span>
        @else
            <span>{{ $contracts->assignTot }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first 'dd(contracts)' then see your contracts structure

Comment: thank you, but I try and "give me null"

Comment: thats why your query is not match what you want

Comment: why the null value give me this error I don't know

Comment: @HimaHima What do you expect the result would be if there is no contact to show ?

Comment: I found the problem in this line but how I go from this problem '->join('users','contracts.conassigneto','users.id')'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object: (using laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593196/errorexception-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-using-laravel)

Comment: Isn't ```Contracts::find($id)``` equivalent to ```Contracts::query()->where(<primary_key>, $id)->first()``` which results in a single Contracts object?. How is it not failing to perform all of the other query builder methods?

Comment: @dparoli that's good but I have multiple returns `return view('admin.contracts.show', compact('contracts','asiTo','tranTo','replies')); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare array `$contracts` like below

```
public function show($id)
{
   $contracts = array();
   $contracts=Contracts::find($id)
    ->where('contracts.id',$id)
    ->join('destination','contracts.condesid','destination.id')
    ->join('department','contracts.condepid','department.id')
    ->leftjoin('users','contracts.conassigneto','users.id')
    ->select('contracts.*','destination.name as desName','department.name  as depName','users.name as assignTot')
    ->first();
     return view('admin.contracts.show', compact('contracts'));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem in this line `->join('users','contracts.conassigneto','users.id')` if conassigneto is null give me error

Comment: Just tell me every time you get `contracts` value or sometimes you get `null`. If you get the value of `contracts` vise versa you use `count` php function. Because when you get `contracts` as null then `assignTot` object is not present. Thats why you get this error

Comment: @A.ANoman no not every time, but when `conassigneto` is null value in contracts table

Comment: @Hima Hima try using left join.. see my edited Answer

Comment: then do a leftJoin to users in the controller and check for emptyness of $contracts->assignTot if you want to use a hyphen.

Comment: @LeenaPatel It's worked nice, thank you :) I accept this answer